# Multicalls doesn't work for Vidyo on iOS

Tags: ios, video-conferencing

I'm making Vidyo iOS application and face an issue with multicalls in Vidyo on iOS - it doesn't work and I don't know why. Can anybody help?

**EDIT:**
iOS version: 9.3.3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For some reason it doesn't work on devices with iOS version less than 10.2.1

Comment: Can you share what error you are seeing with iOS version less that 10.2.1?

Answer (score 1):

Can you share more details about the error you are seeing? Are you creating your own app using vidyo.io or using the vidyo iOS app from the App Store? Both support iOS 9.x 
If you are writing your own app using vidyo.io , try running the iOS sample app from https://developer.vidyo.io/packages on the iOS 9.x device.